# Is there a way to specify that I want all tables in an org-mode file to have specific attributes?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I have an org-mode file with a bunch of tables. In one tree I would like all the tables to have some specific HTML export attributes, but not in others. Is there a way I can do this without having to copy "#+ATTR_HTML: blah" to every table I want to affect?

Comment: Maybe variable ` org-html-table-default-attributes`. See http://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-HTML-export.html#Tables-in-HTML-export

Comment: Was looking at that, but how do I set the value of that variable just for one tree ? Failing that, how can I do that for just one file? Tried setting it as a file variable but that didn't seem to work.